# USB Keyboard stops working after a kernel update

Tags: usb, kernel, keyboard

For any reason, my USB keyboard (045e:0750 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600) stops working when I use any kernel version after version 5.8.0-38 on my Ubuntu 20.04.

The strange part is that it works as expected on the Grub menu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I discovered that for any reason, the package `linux-modules-extra-X.X.X-XX-generic` was not installed. After installing it, my USB keyboard works again.

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-X.X.X-XX-generic
```

> on the previous command, replace the X.X.X-XX with the kernel version that you want.

A way to check if there is a missing `linux-modules-extra-X.X.X-XX-generic` of an installed kernel is:

List the installed kernel versions:

```
dpkg --list | grep "ii" | grep "linux-image"
```

and then, take note of the kernel's version numbers on the second column, and compare with the output of the installed extra kernel modules:

```
dpkg --list | grep "ii" | grep "linux-modules-extra"
```

If an installed kernel version does not have the respective `linux-modules-extra-X.X.X-XX-generic` on the previous command's output, trying to install it and after reboot and checking if it solves the problem.

Comment: Nice to see a solved, with good instructions on how to do it.

Comment: You might be interested in this: `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Since the reported problem is that the keyboard does not work properly with a specific kernel, and `uname -r` returns data from the currently active kernel, so, except that we have a bluetooth keyboard available or access the machine via ssh, the `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` command cannot be typed.